# module :unicode_util not available Phoenix/elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ueberauth

I was trying the [Ueberauth](https://github.com/ueberauth/ueberauth) library for GitHub login. In the login function, I'm getting an error saying that

> "function :unicode_util.lowercase/1 is undefined (module :unicode_util
>   is not available)"

The code that I've used

```
defmodule Discuss.AuthController do
  use Discuss.Web, :controller
  plug Ueberauth

  def callback(conn, params) do
    IO.inspect "++++++++++"
    IO.inspect(conn.assigns)
    IO.inspect "++++++++++"
    IO.inspect(conn.params)
    IO.inspect "++++++++++"
  end
end
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the whole error message including the stacktrace? `unicode_util` was added in Erlang/OTP 20 which is still in RC.

Comment: @Dogbert ok. I've updated it

Comment: Ok, this is caused by the `idna` package accidentally removing compatibility with Erlang < 20. It was fixed in v5.0.2: https://github.com/benoitc/erlang-idna/commit/8dbe87ebc924614eb7fc085a15c34b71b02d9a35. Can you try updating your dependencies to their latest versions? Especially `ueberauth`, and `oauth2` / `hackney` if you have either of these.

Comment: @Dogbert I tried updating using 'mix deps.update --all'. Still getting the same error. Is it the right way to update?

Comment: You could try updating the version numbers of your direct dependencies in `mix.exs` first, before running `deps.update --all`. Can you post your `mix.exs` if that doesn't work?

Comment: @Dogbert here is the mix.exs: http://imgur.com/a/vwSAy

Comment: Can you try upgrading ueberauth to 0.4? I see you're using `~> 0.3` but the latest release is `0.4.0`. Not sure if you'll have to adjust your code for any changes in 0.4.0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147121/discussion-between-gijo-varghese-and-dogbert).